# How to write this method without an if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, multidimensional-array, boolean

Below I have a method I wrote for a project I am doing. I did write it with an if statement, but I want to know how to wite it without one. How can I transfer this coding to not have an if statement?
Thank you!!!

```
public static boolean opposite(boolean verticalToPlay)
{
if(verticalToPlay == true)
{
return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this -

```
public static boolean opposite(boolean verticalToPlay)
{
return !verticalToPlay;
}
```